# How to prevent User from deleting Firebase App

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, devtools

On my Firebase App: Any user can delete my Firebase App by just executing `'firebase.app().delete'`. How do I prevent that from happening?

I tried to block the script by going to Firebase > Authentication > Settings > User Actions > Unchecking "Enable Delete". That did not work.

I tried to splice out the .delete in the firebase.app() by executing 'firebase.app().remove('delete')' but it still does not work

None of them work, How do I fix this? My Firebase Version is 8.6.0

Comment: Deleting the `FirebaseApp` object only affects their own device, so this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem do **you** experience when the user calls that API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `firebase.app().delete()` just [deletes instance of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.app.App#delete) client and that essentially means none of related Firebase services will work unless user refreshes the page. This has *nothing* to do with Firebase Authentication and does not delete user's account.

If you are trying to prevent user from deleting their account by running `firebase.auth().currentUser?.delete()`, then you can uncheck `Enable delete` from [Authentication settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/settings).